# Input numbers (may with leading zero ) but output them without leading zero

Tags: c

I need to preserve any leading zeroes in the input, so I take the digits in as `char`s and then convert them back to integers using the `ctoi()` function, as shown in this code:

```
#include<stdio.h> 

#define ctoi(a)  a-'0'

int main() {
    int n;
    char ch;
    scanf("%c",&n);
    ch=ctoi(n);
    printf("%d",n);
}
```

But that code didn't work.  What is the problem?

```
Input:

001
0123
78
000123

Expected Output:

1
123
78
123

But I got:

1
1
7
1
```

Comment: You need a [`scanf` (and related functions) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). Check the table with all the format codes.

Answer (score 0):

when you store the number as an integer, you only store the actual number, not the formatting used to make that number. If you want to preserve the formatting as is you either need to store it as a string or some other means of storing the original formatting.

```
int n = 10;  // only stores a number in memory
char text[10] = "00010"; // stores any text, but can not be used for number arithmetic as stored here
```

Comment: Worse, OP is using _single_ `char`, not arrays, so only the 1st digit gets kept.